# Drag and drop multiple files by filter into listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm currently have this code to store data to listview
I have to store first the info to textbox lines and then store them to listview.

Is there easy way without storing first textbox and directly put the files into listview?
What I want is to drag and drop or browse the multiple video ts file in the first column and then the srt in the sub column.
hope that you know what I mean. I'm rally new in listview

```
Sub AddToListView()
    LV.Items.Clear()
    Dim vn = vName.Lines
    Dim sn = sName.Lines
    Dim vp = vPath.Lines
    Dim sp = sPath.Lines

    Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)

    Dim upper = {vn.GetUpperBound(0), sn.GetUpperBound(0), vp.GetUpperBound(0), sp.GetUpperBound(0)}
    For I = 0 To upper.Min
        items.Add(New ListViewItem({vn(I), sn(I), vp(I), sp(I)}))
    Next
    LV.BeginUpdate()
    LV.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray())
    SortItems()
    LV.EndUpdate()
    AddToParam()
End Sub

Sub readFiles()
    Dim folder As String = txtinputFolder.Text
    Dim sb1 As New StringBuilder
    Dim sb2 As New StringBuilder
    Dim sb3 As New StringBuilder
    Dim sb4 As New StringBuilder

    For Each item In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ts")
        sb1.Append(item & vbNewLine)
    Next
    vPath.Text = ""
    vPath.Text = sb1.ToString.Trim

    For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ts")
        sb2.Append(Path.GetFileName(file) & vbNewLine)
    Next
    vName.Text = ""
    vName.Text = sb2.ToString.Trim

    For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.srt")
        sb3.Append(Path.GetFileName(file) & vbNewLine)
    Next
    sName.Text = ""
    sName.Text = sb3.ToString.Trim

    For Each item3 In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.srt")
        sb4.Append(item3 & vbNewLine)
    Next
    sPath.Text = ""
    sPath.Text = sb4.ToString.Trim
End Sub
```

Comment: Where in your code do you try and drag/drop anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm not wrong subtitle name should be the same as the movie

```
Sub readFiles(ByVal searchdirectory As String)
    For Each FullPath In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(searchdirectory, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ts")
        Dim parentPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(FullPath)
        Dim movieName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullPath)
        Dim srtPath As String = parentPath & "\" & movieName & ".srt"

        If File.Exists(srtPath) Then
            Lv.Items.Add(FullPath).SubItems.AddRange(New String() {movieName & ".ts", srtPath, movieName & ".srt"})
        Else
            Lv.Items.Add(FullPath).SubItems.AddRange(New String() {movieName & ".ts", "Not Exist", "No subtitle"})
        End If
    Next
    Lv.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
    Lv.Sort()
End Sub
```

usage

```
readFiles("you path")
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you for this
This is what I'm looking for

Comment: Yes the subtitle and movie name is the same file name

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Sub AddToListView(vNames As String(), sNames As String(), vPaths As String(), sPaths As String())
    LV.Items.Clear()

    Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    Dim upperBounds = {vNames.GetUpperBound(0), sNames.GetUpperBound(0), vPaths.GetUpperBound(0), sPaths.GetUpperBound(0)}

    For i = 0 To upperBounds.Min
        items.Add(New ListViewItem({vNames(i), sNames(i), vPaths(i), sPaths(i)}))
    Next

    LV.BeginUpdate()
    LV.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray())
    SortItems()
    LV.EndUpdate()
    AddToParam()
End Sub

Sub readFiles()
    Dim folder As String = txtinputFolder.Text
    Dim vPaths As New List(Of String)
    Dim vNames As New List(Of String)
    Dim sPaths As New List(Of String)
    Dim sNames As New List(Of String)

    For Each filePath In Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.ts")
        vPaths.Add(filePath)
        vNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath))
    Next

    For Each filePath In Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.srt")
        sPaths.Add(filePath)
        sNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath))
    Next

    AddToListView(vNames.ToArray(), sNames.ToArray(), vPaths.ToArray(), sPaths.ToArray())
End Sub
```

If you don't want `readFiles` calling `AddToListView`, you could use fields to store the data rather than local variables, or you could have `readFields` return the data in a `Tuple` or some dedicated object.

This seems like a reasonable answer based on the code provided and the actual question asked but it has nothing to do with drag and drop, so I'm not sure whether I'm missing something or you are.

Comment: Thank you so much this is also helpful for me to understand the using of Sub

Well, I don't have a problem now on drag and drop because I can only drag a folder and get the path only

Comment: I would think that using a `FolderBrowserDialog` in your app would be the most appropriate way to get the folder path, but that's up to you and beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you here's my updated code:
since I want to show first the filename I tried to re-edit the code.

```
Sub readFiles(ByVal searchdirectory As String)
        For Each FullPath In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(searchdirectory, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.ts")
            Dim parentPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(FullPath)
            Dim movieName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullPath)
            Dim srtPath As String = parentPath & "\" & movieName & ".srt"
            Dim allPath As String = parentPath & "\" & movieName

            If File.Exists(srtPath) Then
                LV.BeginUpdate()
                Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
                With lvi
                    .Text = movieName & ".ts" 'video filename
                    .SubItems.Add(movieName & ".srt") 'subtitle filename
                    .SubItems.Add(movieName & ".mkv") 'output filename
                    .SubItems.Add(allPath & ".ts") 'video path
                    .SubItems.Add(allPath & ".srt") 'subtitle path
                End With
                LV.Items.Add(lvi)
                LV.EndUpdate()
            Else
                MsgBox("srt file not found in the folder", vbInformation, "")
            End If
        Next
        LV.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
        LV.Sort()
    End Sub
```